# Запрос вывести клиента в зависимости от кол-во заказов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть:
таблица1 клиент :
клиентID;
наименование;

таблица2 заказы :
заказID;
клиентID;

cвязь KлиентID(первичный ключ в таблице клиент, вторичный заказы)

Надо вывести наименование клиента, у которого больше 5 заказов.

Связал клиента с заказом, а как подсчитать количество заказов, так что бы строка вывода была одна, наверное вложенный подзапрос с COUNT и Distinct в основной, но меня не хватает:( накидайте вариантов:))))

СПАСИБО!.

```
 Select наименование 
 From клиент cl, заказы zak
 where cl.клиентID = zak.клиентID
 --and 5 < (Select Count......))
```

Comment: `group by` и `having` вам помогут, вероятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, наиболее простой из вариантов решения задачи будет использование группировки и предложения [`HAVING`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms184262(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT c.name
FROM clients AS c
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON (o.client_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(o.id) > 5
```

другими вариантами будут различные вариации с CTE и подзапросами для подсчета числа заказов для каждого клиента, а затем фильтрацией в `where`.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает) надо прокачать знания синтаксиса мне))), а возможно с использованием агрегационных функций выполнить запрос типа COUNT (для общего развития)?

Comment: @Kans, поясните. `count` и есть агрегационная функция.

Comment: А вы дополнили ответ, спс)